# How to watch and process (the same way) several files into several outputs with Grunt and/or Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

I am currently using Grunt, and as I was trying Gulp, the same problem I encountered first with Grunt occurred to me.

I am trying to process some js files (concat, uglify and minify them), but I don't want all of them to compile into one big file, I want multiple output files, each from the processing of some input files :

```
scripts =
    firstOutput:
        outputFilename: 'first.min.js',
        inputFiles: ['one.js', 'two.js']

    secondOutput:
        outputFilename: 'second.min.js',
        inputFiles: ['three.js']

    thirdOutput:
        outputFilename: 'third.min.js',
        inputFiles: ['four.js', 'five.js']
```

The only way I found (for now) to achieve that with Grunt is with multiple watches and multiple uglify tasks (or one uglify task and a listener on watch change to dynamically modify the uglify task src and dest) :

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'
    grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-uglify'

    grunt.initConfig
         watch:
             firstOutput:
                 files: scripts.firstOutput.inputFiles
                 tasks: ['uglify:firstOutput']
                 options :
                     spawn : false

             secondOutput:
                 files: scripts.secondOutput.inputFiles
                 tasks: ['uglify:secondOutput']
                 options :
                     spawn : false

             thirdOutput:
                 files: scripts.thirdOutput.inputFiles
                 tasks: ['uglify:thirdOutput']
                 options :
                     spawn : false

         uglify:
             firstOutput:
                 files: scripts.firstOutput.inputFiles
                 dest: scripts.firstOutput.outputFilename

             secondOutput:
                 files: scripts.secondOutput.inputFiles
                 dest: scripts.secondOutput.outputFilename

             thirdOutput:
                 files: scripts.thirdOutput.inputFiles
                 dest: scripts.thirdOutput.outputFilename

    grunt.registerTask 'default', 'watch'
```

And, as you can imagine, this is just an example, in my case of a big web application, there's a lot more than just three output js files, and I also process a few less files into some css files

My Gruntfile is really huge, and I find it has a lot of duplicate code, is there any way to have this code refactored to have one watch and one uglify task, with an automatically guessed src and dest with some kind of dependency (to know that if the four.js file is modified, it has to process the third output) ?

If you have some way to do it with Gulp I'll take it with great pleasure, as I would like to test it in my usual workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this with gulp + vanilla javascript:

```
var _ = require("underscore")
  , gulp = require("gulp")
  , uglify = require("gulp-uglify")

var scripts = [
  {
    output: 'first.min.js',
    input: ['one.js', 'two.js']
  }
  , {
    output: 'second.min.js',
    input: ['three.js']
  }
  , {
    output: 'third.min.js',
    input: ['four.js', 'five.js']
  }
];

function build(files, dest) {

  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));

}

gulp.task("watch", function () {

  _.each(scripts, function (script, i) {

    gulp.watch(script.input, function () {

      build(script.input, script.output);

    });

  });

});
```

**Even better** if you can use globs to match sets of files so you don't have to write out the path for every single `input` set. Something like `input: ["one/**/*.js, "other/**/*.js"]`

Comment: Thank you sir, that works ! I didn't know I could loop for declaring the watches.

Comment: @rhodesjason: Could this possibly be solved differently? For instance: Watch all js-files, and then when for instance common.js changes work out it's dependencies first and then have first.min.js, second.min.js and third.min.js get recompiled?

Comment: @rhodesjason: Should also note that your otherwise great solution here does not output anything to the console when files are edited.

Answer (score -1):

> "I am trying to process some js files (concat, uglify and minify
>   them), but I don't want all of them to compile into one big file"

Can I ask why? The benefit of one larger file is that you save on HTTP requests, every resource you load will cause some slowdown of your website. May I suggest using proper dependency management with RequireJS? That way the optimiser can walk your dependency graph and output optimised files for you.

http://requirejs.org/

There's a grunt task for this too:

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs

Comment: As the WebApp is really big and I'm already doing requests to get a content or to load a functionality, I assumed I could as well get the javascript in the same time, instead of loading a really huge JS the first time.